# Will Entity Framework Clear Query Plans in the Cache that it, itself, did not create?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-execution-plan

We are looking to switch to EF for some of our new applications, and our Database Team has raised concerns about this particular, documented function of the Query Plan Cleanup operation of Entity Framework;

From; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper

1. Once the cache contains a set number of entries (800), we start a timer that periodically (once-per-minute) sweeps the cache.
2. During cache sweeps, entries are removed from the cache on a LFRU (Least frequently – recently used) basis. This algorithm takes both hit count and age into account when deciding which entries are ejected.
3. At the end of each cache sweep, the cache again contains 800 entries.

In the instance that we have 2 'worlds'; one that uses EF, and one that uses Stored Procedures/Ad-hoc queries, will the 'Garbage Collector' of Execution Plans sweep up plans made by our previous implementation?

Comment: You're planning to switch to EF *classic* for new dev? It's probably fair to say that's unusual; if you're actually planning to use EFCore (which confusingly has the same ish version numbers but is 10 years newer) be sure you read documentation for EFC; that link is for EF6, which is definitely not EFCore6

Comment: I wonder which plan cache you're aiming at. The link you refer to is about old and almost deprecated technology.

Comment: @CaiusJard You're entirely right, the versioning is quite...confusing. But my question still stands for EFCore6 surely?

Comment: EF core 6 doesn't have a query plan cache.

Comment: So, number one take away.. You're doing new dev in .NET6/EFCore6 both released in 2021 (or .NET5/EFC5, a bit older). If you see references to "EF" or "Entity Framework" check if it's perhaps EF6 - entity framework "for old apps", latest version 6.4 released in 2019 an evolution of EF6 released in 2013 and EF5 even older. When you ask on SO, use the correct tag..

Comment: To me it's clear that you're talking about the database plan cache which has nothing to do with the EF (4,5,6) plan cache. The DataBase Team jump on one word that happens to overlap their vocabulary but get the wrong end of the stick.